# Writing an "8 bit" (byte) string to a binary file?

Tags: c++

I've tried many of the other threads' recommendations to no avail.

I'm doing huffman's encoding, and the part I'm having trouble with is getting my `string 'byte'` (usually length 8) to write as a character to the output binary file. Whenever I open the output file, the bits are completely different from what I thought I inputted. Additionally, when I output the `char 'c'` after converting the string 'byte' to a byte to a char, the binary of `'c'` doesn't match my original input. For instance, `'c'` would be a 10 bit character, and I'm overall left super confused.

So, how do I do this correctly? Or is the problem maybe elsewhere?

Here's the code:

```c++
if (byte.length() >= 8) {
            bitset<8> b(byte.substr(0, 8));
            c = static_cast<unsigned char>(b.to_ulong());
            flit.write(&c, 1);

    }
```

- `byte` - string that holds my bit characters
- `flit` - ouput file stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you’re trying to represent your bitset as an unsigned long? It sounds like from your description that what you’re trying to do is covered by the functionality of `bitset::to_string` [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_string/)